# Scrape Javascript from web site

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an index.html that includes javascript that shows the date. Using python i need to get the date. Wehn i'm running my python i'm not getting anything

My html

```
<!-- Current Date -->
Current Date:
<input type="text" id="currentDate">
<br><br>
<script>
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  var month = today.getMonth()+1;
  var day = today.getDate()
  if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month }
  if (day < 10) {
    day = "0" + day }
  var date = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
  document.getElementById("currentDate").value = date;
</script>
```

My Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:/Users//github//geckodriver.exe')
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://1.1.1.1:30007')
time.sleep(5)
p_element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='currentDate')
print(p_element.text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

This will return the date varible

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

## Please update your HTTP Link
web_site = 'http://11.1.1.1'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:/geckodriver.exe') # required for selenium firefox driver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(web_site)
time.sleep(10)
p_element = driver.execute_script("return date")
print(p_element)
```